# Redhat Linux Server : Plone installation

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, networkmanager

Unable to install any package using `apt-get` installer it shows

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

-How to install apt-get package over server ?

-I am trying to install Plone over my server so by using following command

```
sudo ./install.sh --target=/home/admin/Plone --build-python zeo
```

it shows following error:

```
Unable to find libz library and headers. These are required to build Python.
Please use your system package or port manager to install libz dev.
(Debian/Ubuntu zlibg-dev)
Exiting now.
```

OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
Plone : Plone-4.3-UnifiedInstaller

How to fix it Please help me ASAP.

Comment: `apt-get` is the package manager for Debian/Ubuntu system and their derivatives.  You are using RedHat, therefore should be using `yum` instead.

Comment: Now are you on Debian or on Redhat? Have you tried to use `yum` instead of `apt-get`?

Answer (score 2):

The default package manager on Red Hat Linux is yum, not apt-get.  Even though one of the error messages you posted mentions Debian/Ubuntu, I'll assume you're using a Red Hat system like your question suggests.  You can probably confirm your Linux distro by using one of the following commands:

```
cat /etc/*-release
lsb_release -a
cat /proc/version
```

There is a Plone documentation page for [Preparing to install Plone](http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/preparing.html) with notes for CentOS, which is essentially a free variant of Red Hat.  That page suggests the following yum install command for dependencies for Plone 5:

```
yum install gcc-c++ patch openssl-devel libjpeg-devel libxslt-devel readline-devel make which python-devel wv poppler-utils
```

Or for dependencies of Plone 4:

```
yum install gcc-c++ patch openssl-devel libjpeg-devel libxslt-devel readline-devel make which python-devel
```

There are, of course, caveats for whether or not you're using the system default version of Python, so you'll want to check that out.  You should also make sure that you're looking at the correct documentation for the version of Plone that you're trying to install.

Once you've installed the dependencies, then you would run the installer as you tried to do previously, assuming the arguments are correct:

```
sudo ./install.sh --target=/home/admin/Plone --build-python zeo
```

Comment: the answer you provided here are not useful for me error remaining same if i am using --build-python option then its showing - Unable to find libz library and headers. These are required to build Python.    and i am using --with-python=/path/ then its showing its not correct path i am using python 2.7

Comment: I don't know why the Plone documentation would provide a one-liner command that doesn't get all the dependencies... Use this to install the libz development files:  yum install zlib-devel

Comment: I tried this to but no result

Comment: You say that you're "using python 2.7", but this doesn't make sense since your command is trying to _build_ Python, not use an existing installation. Does "no result" mean that nothing was installed? Or zlib-devel was installed, but python still does not build? If you're using new commands and getting new errors, you should post what you did and the error message you're getting. You might also want to answer the following: 1) what OS and version are you running; 2) what version of Plone are you trying to install?

Comment: I added OS and Plone Unified installer version in question

Comment: Are you still trying to build Python with the Plone installer or are you using a version of Python already installed on your system?

Comment: I am still trying to build Python with the Plone installer

Comment: What happened when you tried "yum install zlib-devel"?  You said "no result", but was there an installation message or an error message at all?

Comment: This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package zlib-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: It looks like you haven't registered your Red Hat system's subscription. You should fix that or configure other package repositories before trying to install packages from yum. Do you have a valid subscription?

Comment: Finally mostly problem resolved after registering the product but it showing en error:Unable to find libssl or openssl/ssl.h.
libssl and its development headers are required for Plone.
Please install your platform's openssl-dev package
and try again.
(If your system is using an SSL other than openssl or is
putting the libraries/headers in an unconventional place,
you may need to set CFLAGS/CPPFLAGS/LDFLAGS environment variables
to specify the locations.)
I installed yum install openssl-devel but after that it remain same

Comment: "Unable to find libssl or openssl/ssl.h. libssl and its development headers are required for Plone. Please install your platform's openssl-dev package and try again." My answer included the command from the Plone documentation to install all of the dependencies that you need. Saying "it remain the same" doesn't really tell us what happened. Did it install? Did the install fail? If it installed correctly, did you get a new error message when trying to install Plone?